# When to return ConflictResult in a Web Api Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In Asp.NET Web Api Projects , one of the Http result datatypes which could be returned in a controller is
[ConflictResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn338034(v=vs.118).aspx). When would you return this type of result in your response?

I could not find a proper example and explanation on this status and I hope your response would contain sample code and the explanation of the reason why the existing status such as BadRequestResult,ExceptionResult,InternalServerResult were not as applicable as ConflictResult?

Comment: to quote from http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E409.html

This particular code can be returned when "The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the request submitted by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) can not be completed because it conflicts with some rule already established. For example, you may get a 409 error if you try to upload a file to the Web server which is older than the one already there - resulting in a version control conflict."

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Why couldn't we accommodate this conflicting result into the existing response types? How about the sample code?

Comment: Well you could use any of them in your code but if you have an IHttpActionResult implementation for a specific HttpStatus code you should use that. I think the question you are asking is why should a webserver return 409 when same thing can be achieved by a 500.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this response in scenarios where the same record is updated simultaneously by two users. E.g. an edit conflict or if there is a version conflict between existing data and the update request.

It will return a Http Status Code 409

Each one of the RequestResult mentioned have a different meaning and allows the client to handle the response differently. A listing of all the [HTTP Status Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.118).aspx) are provided in the link.

The ones specified by you are detailed below

**BadRequestResult**

> Equivalent to HTTP status 400. BadRequest indicates that the request could not be understood by the server. BadRequest is sent when no other error is applicable, or if the exact error is unknown or does not have its own error code.

**ConflictResult**

> Equivalent to HTTP status 409. Conflict indicates that the request could not be carried out because of a conflict on the server.

**InternalServerResult**

> Equivalent to HTTP status 500. InternalServerError indicates that a generic error has occurred on the server.

The reason you would implement ConflictResult as against InternalServerResult or any other would be to have your implementation adhere to standards as much as possible and return a very specific result. The same reason as why you would return a IOException and not just Exception.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your response and provide sample code demonstration? Also why not incorporate this conflicting result into the existing types such as BadRequestResult,ExceptionResult,InternalServerResult?

Comment: So, not to return it. It seems we cannot do that.